# How to mount NTFS partition image in Windows created with dd on Linux?

Tags: windows, windows-10, dd, ddrescue

As per the title, I need to work with an image created from Linux via `ddrescue /dev/sda3 image.img` in Windows. Notice that this is an image of a partition, not the entire drive.

How can this be mounted in Windows 10?

Comment: Which kind of partition have you made? You need 3rd party software if this is not a FAT or NTFS partition like EXT3, BTRFS, etc. else see https://winaero.com/mount-iso-img-files-windows-10/

Comment: @TomKuschel It's in the title.

Comment: Since it appears to be easily missed in the title, I also added it to the body.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great and free tool that works well for this:

https://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

[image: mounted]

Steps:

[image: select image]

[image: select entire image]

(No Step 3 with these options)

[image: select correct options]